# block the hash anchor from scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <li> <a href="#calculate">Calculate</a></li>
 <li> <a href="#calculate1">Calculate1</a></li>
 <li> <a href="#calculate2">Calculate2</a></li>
```

this is the code I have, when I click on the link the page scrolls down to where #calculate is,which is understandable. But I need it to not scroll
I can remove the value of the href,is there anyway to block it from scrolling WITHOUT removing the value #calculate and without changing the id names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ebvbn/)**

In modern jQuery versions:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Other jQuery versions:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li > a[href*=calculate]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the page scroll

  // continue other code

});
```

Read about **[.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault)**

Here, `'li > a[href*=calculate]'` will select those anchor tags which are direct(first level) children of `li` and contains `calculate` word in their `href` attribute.

Comment: Your selector is wrong, `~` is used for selecting one a space separated list of items in the attribute, what you want is `*`

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a function to the click event and have it return false.

```
$("a").click(function() { return false; });
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/atasix/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just prevent the default action of the link

```
$('li > a[href^=#calculate]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

`'li > a[href^=#calculate]'` selects an `a` element whose href attribute begins with `#calculate` that is a child of an `li` element

[**More Info**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors)